# Primefaces two or more global confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

Is there any way to have two or more global confirm dialog in Primefaces 5.0?

This code below from primefaces documentation and global confirmDialog is a nice feature.

```
<h:form>           
  <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />

  <p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" actionListener="#{dialogView.destroyWorld}" update="message">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
  </p:commandButton>

  <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
     <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
     <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
  </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

But in my case i need two of them.

Something like; first dialog have 'yes' and 'no' button, second have 'send' and 'cancel' buttons.

Comment: No you can't. Think of it, how would that behave? Which one should be shown first? But I don't think you actually need real global ones, but rather 'a confirm dialog for a certain amount of controls and another one for other controls'. Well, simply looking at the docs does not show a solution, so the chance is big it is is not going to be easy. But what you can try to achieve is to have two groups of buttons in there and see if you can achieve to show either the first group or the second group, based on what commandButton is clicked.

Comment: But that 'workaround' would probably result in a fair amount of custom code and/or things that in fact does not make it really global anymore, so using two non-global dialog would probably not be that different

Comment: First global confirm for saving, second for save and submit, third one is for delete process. It could be like `<p:confirm id="globalSave" ...` and `<p:confirm id="globalDelete" ...`

Comment: Of course i can do it other ways but if it was possible it will be easy to implement whole project.

Comment: Giving them two id's is what it does, giving them two id's. But how would you define which one to use? If you don't want to do it on the buttons, you'd have to do it on the confirmDialog which in my opinion defeats the advantage of being 'global'. So defining three somewhere (in a template) and pointing to one of the three in each commandButton that requires confirmation is imo the right way to go.